# Unable to edit files and folders over Samba

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I am running Samba v4.2.10-Debian on my Raspberry Pi 2B (running Raspbian Jessie) and have set up a `fstab` file to mount my external drive on `/dev/sda1` to `/media/ECHO`:

`/dev/sda1 /media/ECHO auto noatime 0 0`.

My Samba configurations are default except `SECURITY = USER` and my share definition.

`[ECHO]
comment = ECHO NAS
path = /media/ECHO/
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
writeable = yes`

I can read/write `/media/ECHO` from my account through SSH, however, when I connect through Samba, I am not allowed to modify anything. However this works if I set `uid=justin` in the `fstab` (which is not ideal because it wouldn't work for other users).

`/media/ECHO` is exFAT (exfat-fuse is installed) and mounted as `drwxr-xr-x` owned by root (group and user).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your 'user' inside 'users' group?

Comment: All of my users are indeed inside the `users` group.

Comment: Try replacing `auto` by `defaults` in `fstab`. If this works, but you regard it as insecure then you can turn off some of the equivalent options `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async`. Or you can try `gid=users` if this group has the write permissions you require.

Comment: I managed to get it working by setting `gid=users` and `umask=002`, but thanks to everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your mount command, provide the Group with Write permission, and change the owner-group to Users, or alternately, allow the Other group write permissions.

Normally you would use the commands below:
`sudo chown -R root:users /media/ECHO; sudo chmod -R 775 /media/ECHO`

or

`sudo chmod o+w /media/ECHO`

but since you are using ex-fat, you will have to edit it in FSTAB instead.

samba permissions stack atop filesystem permissions, so even if you tell samba to allow write, it won't unless the filesystem also provides that user the same write permissions. Based on your permissions (755), only the owner (root) could write.

Adding an umask to the fstab does this if you're using exfat-fuse.

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to get it working now. Although I had tried multiple ways to set it to RW, I never tried umask. It suddenly came to me that I should've probably googled exfat-fuse with fstab read/write to search for answers, and that's what I got. I've added what did it for me to your answer for people coming here looking for solutions.